# Unix Command (Mac OS): cut and move rows

Tags: macos, perl, bash, shell, unix

Could you please give me a hint which unix command I can use to do the following:

I want to convert these lines...

```
1   a   i  
2   b   ii  
3   c   iii  
4   d   iv  
5   e   v  
6   f   vi  
7   g   vii  
8   h   viii  
9   i   xi
```

...into those:

```
1   a   i   4   d   iv  7   g   vii  
2   b   ii  5   e   v   8   h   viii  
3   c   iii 6   f   vi  9   i   xi
```

`rs`and `perl -pne` just transpose them but I need a completely new arrangement as you see. Perl-code would be favored, but I am thankful for any help.

cheers
marsch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -lne 'push @{$l[($.-1) % 3]}, $_; }{ print "@$_" for @l' data.txt | column -t
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-l`: Enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){..}` loop for each line in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `push @{$l[($.-1) % 3]}, $_;`: Push each line into an array modulo the line number
- `}{ print "@$_" for @l`: Print the 3 element array at end of processing
- `| column -t`: Even out the columns

Answer (score 2):

I would go with `split` and `paste` from `coreutils`. Try the following commands:

```
split -l3 infile
paste -d' ' xaa xab xac | column -t
```

Output:

```
1  a  i    4  d  iv  7  g  vii
2  b  ii   5  e  v   8  h  viii
3  c  iii  6  f  vi  9  i  xi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a oneliner:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; push @a,$_ if $_; unless($. % 3) {push @f,[@a]; @a = undef; shift @a} END {for my $i (@f) { for (@$i) {print "$_ "} print "\n"}}' filename.txt
```

output

```
1 a i 2 b ii 3 c iii
4 d iv 5 e v 6 f vi
7 g vii 8 h viii 9 i xi
```

Comment: Sorry, but the order does not fit my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

I use ruby

```
string = "1   a   i  
2   b   ii  
3   c   iii  
4   d   iv  
5   e   v  
6   f   vi  
7   g   vii  
8   h   viii  
9   i   xi "
ary = string.split("\n")
length = ary.size / 3
new_ary = Array.new(3, "")

ary.each_with_index do |e, i| 
  position = i % 3
  new_ary[position] += e
end

puts new_ary.join("\n")
```

Hope to help:)